# MICE: what does returned df mean?

Tags: data-imputation, multiple-imputation, degrees-of-freedom, mice

In MICE, the object returned by pool() has a component, df, which is included in the summary of the pooled analysis.  In my analysis I have about 55,000 cases, but the returned df is higher for most variables than 900,000.  What does this value of df refer to?

Comment: The df refer to the degrees of freedom to be used in statistical testing. They can be higher because since we are "filling in the data" many times, we now have more information than we did before.

I'd probably butcher it if I tried to explain the theory about it all in a comment/answer right now, so I will refer you to van Buurens book "Flexible imputation of missing data", chapter 2, pages 40-43. Go check that out. If you cannot access that book, I can write out in an answer what he says here, but it will take a while (because there are so many parts to it and I need to get back to work).

Comment: Many thanks.  I think that I have access to van Buuren's book.  I'll look it up there.  Thanks for the reference.  Larry Hunsicker

Answer (score 2):

For those without access to van Buuren's book, here is what the degrees of freedom mean. I am taking the steps pretty much directly from his book (which I think that you should buy, it is awesome!). We need to set up a lot of definitions first.

Our goal is to estimate a scientific estimand Q (this could be a regression coefficient, mean, etc.). In MICE, we do this by imputing $m$ datasets, running each analysis on each of the $m$ datasets, and then pooling the results.

To make this example easy to follow, let us suppose we are interested in a regression coefficient, and we impute $m=50$ times. We can find our average coefficient ($\bar{Q}$) by taking the average of each coefficient from our $l$ imputed datasets ($\hat{Q}_l$). So, we have that

$$\bar{Q}=\frac{1}{50}\sum_{l=1}^{m=50}\hat{Q}_l$$

Within each imputed dataset, we have a variance ($\bar{U}_l$) for the coefficient. $\bar{U}_l$ is really the var-covariance matrix of $\hat{Q}_l$, but since we have a scalar in this example, so too is $\bar{U}_l$. We may compute the average complete data var by doing

$$\bar{U}=\frac{1}{50}\sum_{l=1}^{m=50}\bar{U}_l$$

Between each dataset for the same coefficient, we also have variance. This is given by

$$B=\frac{1}{m-1}\sum_{l=1}^{m}(\hat{Q}_l-\bar{Q})(\hat{Q}_l-\bar{Q})'$$

Once again, we only have a scalar in this example, so it will just be the square of the estimated coefficient minus the average of that coefficient.

Lastly, we may define the total variance from imputation as

$$T=\bar{U}+B+\frac{B}{M}$$
Which is the variation from within + variance between + simulation error

For a scalar Q, we may define the proportion of variance attributed to the missing data as

$$\lambda = \frac{B+\frac{B}{m}}{T}$$

To interpret this, if we see that a lot of our variation is due to our sampling, this, $\lambda$ will be close to 1. If there is no simulation of between variance, this will be 0.

We may define r as the relative increase in variance due to non response as

$$r=\frac{B+\frac{B}{M}}{\bar{U}}$$

This can also be written in terms of $\lambda$

$$r=\frac{\lambda}{1-\lambda}$$

Now, the old degrees of freedom, as defined by Rubin in 1987 is given by

$$\nu_{old}=(m-1)(1+\frac{1}{r^2})$$
Which can also be written as 
$$\frac{m-1}{\lambda^2}$$

However, this can be larger than the degrees of freedom, so in 1999, Barnard and Rubin proposed a new one. Letting

$$\nu_{com}=n-k$$
where n is the number of data points we have, and k is the number of parameters in a HYPOTHETICAL COMPLETE DATA.

We can then get a number called $\nu_{obs}$ by doing

$$\nu_{obs}=\frac{\nu_{com}+1}{\nu_{com}+3}\nu_{com}(1-\lambda)$$

Finally, we can get the degrees of freedom as

$$\nu=\frac{\nu_{old}\nu_{obs}}{\nu_{old}+\nu_{obs}}$$

So that is the theory behind what it ought to be.

However, you are getting a number that is above your total sample size. I believe this has to do with the mice package.

We can see [function mice.df()](https://github.com/stefvanbuuren/mice/blob/a2944b82e8b96cd40f6cfd041a685346a97e1c2f/R/mice.df.r) will set the common degrees of freedom to 999999 if it can't find any. This is later called in the [pool function](https://github.com/stefvanbuuren/mice/blob/a2944b82e8b96cd40f6cfd041a685346a97e1c2f/R/pool.r) on line 198. It tries to get the degrees of freedom residual from [here](https://github.com/stefvanbuuren/mice/blob/a2944b82e8b96cd40f6cfd041a685346a97e1c2f/R/df.residual.r), but it is returning a null. I guess the method that you are using doesn't have a way to get the $\nu_{com}$, so that is why this is happening.

So, I can offer few solutions, because I don't know the exacts of yours...

1. calculate all of the degrees of freedom by yourself (this might
   actually be easier)
2. Go into the code and change the default 999999
   to something more reasonable.
3. Go into the df residuals code and
   add code to allow you to get the df for your specific method.

Also, if @StefvanBuuren is on here, can you explain why the default for large sample/unknown $\nu_{com}$ is set at 999999?

**Edits**
I looked back at some code I did, and saw I was getting huge df's too. I am running a coxph model. But notice that we cannot get the df from here. because

```
class(coxph_obj$analyses[[1]])
[1] "coxph"

coxph_obj$analyses[[1]]$df.residual
NULL

df.residual(coxph_obj$analyses[[1]])
NULL

mn <- try(f <- fitted(coxph_obj$analyses[[1]]), silent = TRUE)
mn
NULL
```

So, it seems like even though the df is in fact available, the current code is not taking advantage of it, and thus defaults to using 9999999.

Comment: Ray:  This is an excellent and clear presentation of the calculation of df in pool().  Many thanks.  You also both confirm my suspicion that there was a bug in pool(), and you even seem to have located the bug!!  I do have Stef's book, and it is as good as you say it is.  Larry Hunsicker

Comment: I actually sent Dr. Van Buuren an email about this, hopefully he will respond back. I don't know what kind of object you are using if it isn't a cox model, but you might want to toy around with it to get out what you need, compute it on your own, and then substitute it back in the summary.

Comment: It's a Cox model, just like yours.  I can follow your calculation to get the correct values.  I also sent Stef an email.  He hasn't replied, but I wouldn't be surprised if a fix turned up in the next version of the mice package.

Comment: As well, I am not sure that the equality between the $\nu_{old}$, derived from $r$ and the one derived with $\lambda$ are equal. I think it should be $\nu_{old}=(m-1)(1+\frac{1}{r^2})=\frac{m-1}{2+\lambda^{-1}*(\lambda^{-1} -2)}$ . Can anyone confirm this?